# Altium Designer - Prevent snapping when using the "Measure Distance" tool

Tags: altium

I want to measure the distance from point a to point b in the PCB editor. However point b is surrounded by pads and primitives, thus when I try to move my cursor to point b, the cursor keeps snapping to the pads and primitives. Under normal circumstances I love this snapping feature, but sometimes I require a specific measurement that the snapping feature prevents me from doing.

Is there a method to quickly switch between snapping and non-snapping when using the "Measurement Distance"  tool?

Comment: Hold down the Control key to turn off snapping temporarily. Or adjust the snap feature how you like it.

Comment: @ThePhoton You beat me to it, I was just about to say this

Comment: Works great, thank you! I will answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to The Photon for providing the solution.

Hold down the Control key to temporarily turn off snapping. Release the Control key to go back to snapping.